# tag: function word

Tags: discussion

I miss a tag like function word. The most difficult words in the dictionary of English and all other languages are function words. 
The thread "Is this subjunctive?" in ELU concerned with "come+time" has the tags meaning, grammar, subjunctive-mood. That is of the vaguest kind, but no precise labelling.

I find the system how tags are presented very confusing and unsystematic. It is very difficult to see what choices there are as to tags. I think one should consider a new arrangement of the sector tags.

Comment: We need a FAQ post for "Is this subjunctive?" "NO."

Comment: I did not talk about FAQ. With such sort reactions you don't encourage to partcipate in Meta.

Comment: My comment was only tangentially related to your post, which is why I posted it as a comment not an answer.

Comment: *Function word* is a superclass; ELU tags are more granular.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You mean like [tag:grammar] and [tag:meaning]?

Comment: No, like *preposition* and *pronoun* and the like.

Comment: `function-word` as a tag has not been created yet? If not yet, no one else has found it useful. You can find out which ones exist by going to the 'tag' area and looking around.

Comment: Is a factitive(affirm, nominate, pass sentence on) the same as a function word? If not, please, what?

Comment: You can create any tag you want. I have created maybe four or five tags at the most. For example: *adverb-position* and *social-media*.  If you believe the tag *function* is needed, then go ahead and edit the tags in  your posts or somebody else's post. A short description to explain what "function" is, and whoever wants to tag their question "function" will have that option available.